# Entity Framework with a layered web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, architecture

I know that this question seems to be already made here, but I have specific doubts, **mainly in database-first usage** and lack of code-example in replied questions.

I have these layers: Core, Data and UI (asp.net mvc).
I have these tables in MSSQL: Person and Contact.

Question 1: In data layer, EDMX generates Person and Data POCO. Where I write methods like `SearchPersonByCity()` ? Do I need to create another Person class in the same data layer, just for writting data CRUD? How I make this? Please make an example (classes, namespaces, etc.. not necessary the whole actual code)

Question 2: How do I transpose these data between data-layer and core (domain models)? Where do I need to create the same `SearchPersonByCity()` in core (domain) class? Maybe create another Person class in core-layer just for these data-acess methods?

Please give me some code example, and how big companies do in real life, because it seems to be so dumb and a lot of code to mantain and problaby I'm getting something wrong.

I'm not lazy, and I read hundreds pages of Entity Framework books, questions here, and I can't figure out how to do this in code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I would use the repository pattern in your case, so first you have a IRepository  class defined:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : 
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T GetById(long id);
    T GetById(string id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
}
```

And an abstract base RepositoryBase class:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private PersonDBEntities dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected PersonDBEntities DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }
    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Add(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (T obj in objects)
        dbset.Remove(obj);
    }
    public virtual T GetById(long id)
    {
        return dbset.Find(id);
    }
    public virtual T GetById(string id)
    {
        return dbset.Find(id);
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbset.ToList();
    }

    //You can return IQueryable if you want to build your expression true later on...
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

And your PersonRepository class:

```
public class PersonRepository: RepositoryBase<Person>, IPersonRepository
    {
    public PersonRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
        {
        }           
    }
public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person> // Person will be your POCO class
{
}
```

Next step is on your service layer, you will define and implement that actual SearchPersonByCity() method:

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository personRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public PersonService(IPersonRepository personRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> SearchPersonByCity(string city)
    {
        var persons = personRepository.Get(p => p.City == city);
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Comment: But one thing. My EDMX is in Repository layer, right? So as POCO Person class that you're working in service layer. UI layer (asp.net mvc) will access these Repository's auto generated data-entities?

Comment: Repositories object will be in the same layer as your EDMX entity model object is. The EDMX is your dbcontext. Your Repository base class will contain an instance of the dbcontext. You can put your POCO classes in a domain model layer. UI layer (mvc) can only access the service layer which is a wrapper layer to call your repositories  method.

Comment: "You can put your POCO classes in a domain model layer" how? In your code example you're returning DATA-MODEL to the services, and it'll use DATA-MODEL in UI, that's wrong. It should return domain-model or view-model to work in UI, right? So, how it would be?

Comment: Yes you can do that but in my opinion that is a bit of over archiecture. POCO classes can be as well used as your business object. You might want to add a business object of your Person POCO class, and in the SearchPersonByCity method, map the POCO Person class to your business Person class, return IEnumerable<PersonBusiness> instead.